# What means "xs @ _*" in PathList of SBT assembly-plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

What these phrases mean:

> xs @ _*
>
> ps @ _*

Copied from [documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy):

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case "application.conf"                            => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "unwanted.txt"                                => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In your example `_*` means everything, `@` for matching

`xs @ _*` is case pattern means pick every thing that matched for first case `/javax/servlet/*`

`ps @ _*`  means pick up all that match as /* and with `html` extension

Answer (score 4):

'@' operator is used to bind to variables in pattern matching.

`<somevar> : _*` is used to unpack varargs as sequence of appropriate type.

In this example `ps @ _*` tells pattern matching to retrieve varargs from PathList as Sequence of paths.

Comment: Is it Scala regex syntax?